# Hdparm set pasword went wrong

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, hdparm

I wanted to erase my ssd and so i set a password the drive in order to complete a ATA Secure Erase. Normaly the passwort get reset to NULL after completion of the erase.

Then however I realised that i have some data on the drive and wanted to copy that away, but my drive is not recognised any more! What should I do? I am working with Ubuntu.

Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk is now in a password-locked state.

If you only completed the password setting phase, you would need to use `hdparm --security-unlock` and/or `hdparm --security-disable`, both with the password you used when setting the drive password. If you used the `--user-master` option when setting the password, you'll need to use it when unlocking and/or disabling it too.

If you already sent the `hdparm --security-erase` command, the drive will remember the command even if you disconnect power from it, and will not respond to further commands until the erase procedure is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the negative answer, but
ATA Secure Erase erases all the data, and it will not be recoverable by even
data recovery services.

So if the ATA Secure Erase has finished correctly, your data is truly erased and lost.